# How to remove specific multiple marker from google map instead of single or all marker

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I want to remove multiple specific markers from Google Maps but I can't do it. I already know about  `marker.remove();` and `mMap.clear();` but they don't help me. Look at the code below how I create multiple marker.

```
    private ArrayList<String> pup_latList01;
    private ArrayList<String> pup_longList01;
    private ArrayList<String> pup_nameList01;

    for(int i = 0 ;i< pup_nameList01.size();i++)
    {
       LatLng puplatlang = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(pup_latList01.get(i)),Double.parseDouble(pup_longList01.get(i)));
       pupMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(puplatlang).title(pup_nameList01.get(i)).draggable(true).icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(MapsActivity.this, R.drawable.bus_stop_small)));
    }
```

I want to remove marker only from create from `pupMarker` Marker object.
I also have other marker created from other objects. When I use `pupMarker.remove();` it removes only last created marker from above code
and `mMap.clear();` removes all markers from the map.

Comment: In addition to managing `Marker` results, you may need to `setTag` `getTag` to identify specific ones of interest (like setting it with `i`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code pupMarker is always the last marker on the list. So when you use `pupMarker.remove();` it only removes the last created marker. You can make a List that will hold all these Markers and then get the one you want to remove.

Edit 1:

It's probably better to use HashMap instead of List for holding references to Markers. It will be easier later to find it with a key in the Map.

Edit 2:

Example of this as requested in the comment:

```
private HashMap<Integer, Marker> hashMapMarker = new HashMap<>();

for(int i = 0 ;i< pup_nameList01.size();i++)
       {
       LatLng puplatlang = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(pup_latList01.get(i)),Double.parseDouble(pup_longList01.get(i)));
       Marker pupMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(puplatlang).title(pup_nameList01.get(i)).draggable(true).icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(MapsActivity.this, R.drawable.bus_stop_small)));
hashMapMarker.put(i, pupMarker);
       }
```

Note that if using Integer for a key is probably better to use SparseArray instead of HashMap.

```
private void removeMarker(int position){
     hashMapMarker.get(positon).remove();
     hashMapMarker.remove(position);
}
```

Comment: can you please give me one example of this?

Comment: I have updated the answer. If you are not familiar with Maps you can use List for this.

Comment: thanks you solution with some modification its work for me sorry for late response.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a marker with googleMap.addMarker(...), you receive a Marker object, which represents it.
That is, each marker object for each marker on the map.

So, for example, you would add markers you like in a specific list group.

Steps:

1. Create a list of type List, for example.
2. For each marker you receive on googleMap.addMarker(...) add it on the list.
3. For clear all those specificis markers loop the list with a for each and use the Marker.remove(); method.
4. Clear the list with List.clear();

Comment: can you please give some example with snipped code for this?